# using sed to replace two patterns within a larger pattern

Tags: sed, find-and-replace

Using sed how could I replace two patterns within a larger pattern on a single line?

Given a single line of text I want to find a pattern (Let's call this the outer pattern) and then within that outer pattern replace two inner patterns.

Here's a one line example of the input text:

```
Z:\source\private\main\developer\foo\setenv.sh(25):     export 'FONTCONFIG_PATH'="$WINE_SHARED_SUPPORT/X11/etc/fonts"
```

In the example above the outer pattern is `/^.*\([[:digit:]]+\):/` which should equal `Z:\source\private\main\developer\foo\setenv.sh(25):` The two inner patterns are `/^[A-Za-z]:/` and `/\\/`.

Another way to phrase my question is:

Using sed I know how to perform replacements of a pattern using the `s` command, but how do I limit the range of `s` command so it only works on the portion of the input string up to the `(25):`?

The ultimate result I am trying to get is the line of text is transformed into this:

```
/enlistments/source/private/main/developer/foo/setenv.sh(25):     export 'FONTCONFIG_PATH'="$WINE_SHARED_SUPPORT/X11/etc/fonts"
```

Answer (score 1):

This command converts your input example to your output example:

```
sed 's|\\|/|g;s|^[^/]*|/enlistments|'
```

If some of your input contains backslashes in the portion after the `/^.*([[:digit:]]+):/` part, then you will have to divide and conquer to prevent those latter backslashes from being replaced.

```
sed 'h;s/^.*([[:digit:]]\+)://;x;s/^\(.*([[:digit:]]\+):\).*/\1/;s|\\|/|g;s|^[^/]*|/enlistments|;G;s/\n//'
```

Explanation (steps marked with an asterisk (**`[*]`**) apply to both commands):

- `h` - copy the line to hold space
- `s/^.*([[:digit:]]\+)://` - delete the first part of the line from the original in pattern space
- `x` - swap pattern space and hold space
- `s/^\(.*([[:digit:]]\+):\).*/\1/` - keep the first part of the line from the copy (discard the last part)
- `s|\\|/|g` - **[`*`]** change all the backslashes to slashes (in the divide-and-conquer version, only the portion in pattern space - the first part of the line - is affected)
- `s|^[^/]*|/enlistments|` - **[`*`]** change whatever appears before the first slash into "/enlistments" - this could be made more selective if needed
- `G` - append a newline and the contents of hold space onto the end of pattern space
- `s/\n//` - remove the interior newline

Answer (score 0):

There are two facts that I think you'll find useful:

1. By default, `sed` will only replace the first occurrence of a string in a line.  So given the following line:

   ```
   foo foo
   ```

   The command `sed s/foo/bar/` will result in:

   ```
   bar foo
   ```
2. You can limit a sed command to lines matching a specific pattern.  If you want to perform the above substitution only on lines containing the string "xyz", you would use a command like this:

   ```
   sed '/xyz/ s/foo/bar/'
   ```

I think this should help you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sed -r 's/^[A-Z]:\\|\\/\//g' | sed 's/^/\/enlistments/'
```

Now, this of course requires that there's no backslashes in the part after (25): to work. But as I suspect this will never be the case due to unix path structure this will never be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/([0-9]\+):/&\n/;h;s/\n.*//;y/\\/\//;s/[^/]*/\/enlistments/;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```