# Replace text inside matched pattern?

Tags: find-and-replace

Using any stream editor, (or vim), is there a fast, efficient yet simple way to do a substitution but only inside an already matched pattern. for example :

Replace all parameter "foo" with "bar" but only for the function "func" :

```
test(foo, baz) func(foo) truc(foo) func(test, foo)
```

->

```
test(foo, baz) func(bar) truc(foo) func(test, bar)
```

would be done by first searching : `/func\((.*)\)/`

...And then, inside the captured group (or at least the full match), do `s/foo/bar/g`

NOTE : I've read [using sed to replace two patterns within a larger pattern](https://superuser.com/questions/236860/using-sed-to-replace-two-patterns-within-a-larger-pattern?rq=1)

But I'm looking for a simpler way, not necessarily using sed

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++ editor, it also works with SublimeText (at least V3.0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bfunc\([^)]*\K\bfoo\b`
- Replace with: `bar`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\bfunc\(    # literally func(, word boundary to avoid abcfunc
[^)]*       # 0 or more not closing parenthese
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\bfoo\b     # foo surrounded with word boundaries
```

**Result for given example:**

```
test(foo, baz) func(bar) truc(foo) func(test, bar)
```